# remote connecting to sql server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i try to remote connecto to my sql server i get this eror;

```
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: A network-related or instance-specific 
error occurred while establishing a`connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that 
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - 
Could not open a connection to SQL Server) 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)`
```

My sql server is running on my windows 8.1 single language edition machine. I also have iis server running on it. and i can view the page from remote machine with no problem. Here are the list that i have done;
I opened port 1433 and 1434 and forwarded them to my machine.
I closed all firewalls.
SQL browser is running
İ can ping my ip.

I can connect the sql server from office with just writing the ip 192.168.2.18. My instance name is . However i can not connect it from outside of the office. What is i am doing wrong what must be my server name when connecting to the instance . Can i connect it by just ip  without writing any instance name?

Comment: you will not have same ip at home as well

Comment: Your problem is with IPV4 - not with SQL - you can't connect to machine  without public ip (i.e. in local network) ouside of local network; if you want to do that you have to have a machine with public ip & setup forwarding to your sql server.

Comment: I have public ip 144.122.180.147 and forwarded the request to my computer running in ip: 192.168.2.18 I can connec to sql server with 192.168.2.18 inside office but con not connect with 144.122.180.147